# How to access state values from a different class in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a search bar that filters out a set of data. The search function I made uses several states to filter results. When the search bar and results page are in the same class, the search function works but what I'm trying to do now is separate the search bar and display the search results on a separate page. Here's the state being set in the SearchBar class.

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      names: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

The problem is I have no idea how to get the data stored in the SearchBar class to be displayed on the results page. Here's how I'm filtering the results on the results page.

```
const filteredData = data.filter(entry => (entry.name === (this.state.names))
```

This data is being filtered in the Search class but `this.state.names` is being stored in the SearchBar class. This SearchBar class is being displayed on my header where users can search for whatever they want and after they press search, the results page appears. So how can I take the data stored in the SearchBar class and use it in a different class?

UPDATE: I tried passing in the state to the Search class in the render function but that causes the entire page to just freeze.

```
render() {

  return (
    <Search names = {this.state.names} />
  )
}
```

Comment: I failed to follow the train of thought , would you mind adding code and then pointing as to what you want to achieve

Comment: You'll need to pull the state up to a parent component, then pass it down via props (usual) or Context (not as common). Alternately you could use something like Redux but that's probably overkill if this is your only issue.

Comment: And how is that supposed to be done because I tried doing ```<Search names = {this.state.names} />``` in the render function in the SearchBar class and now my page doesn't load up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please paste your code ? as its a bit difficult to understand that what you are trying to achieve exactly

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly but:

1. You can make a new component to store your data.
2. Then use this function (or similar) in onChange on that component

   ```
    const filterData = (e) => {
     const valueToCheck = e.target.value
     let newArr = []
        for(entry of data) {
        // do the logic
        //push the data you want into an array
        newArr.push(entry)
        }
     setState(newArr)
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

SearchBar should call onSearchResults([...]) callback and then `PageResult` may accept those results, you need a component that orchestrate all.

```js
const App = () =>{
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  return (<>
    <SearchBar onSearchChange={setResults}/>
    { results.length && <PageResult results={results}/> }
  </>)
}
```

SearchBar will call `props.onSearchChange(results)` with the filtered data. App component will react to that change and send those results to PageResult component